# Populate multiple cells within a summary sheet using SumIf

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate multiple cells within a summary sheet by using the SUMIF formula in VBA.

I have two sheets - Summary and CPTView.
I want cell C7 to populate the result of the SumIf formula. I want it to look in CPTView A:A for dates that match Summary cell C4 and sum CPTView C:C.

I want to avoid using Application.WorksheetFunction because I want this cell to re-calculate when the data is changed.

```vb
Private Sub summarypage()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

Dim cptrng As Range
Dim sumrng As Range
Dim cpt As String

Set cptrng = Sheets("CPTView").Range("A1:A1000")
Set sumrng = Sheets("CPTView").Range("C1:C1000")
cpt = ws.Range("C4").Value

ws.Range("C7").Formula = "=SumIf(cptrng, cpt, sumrng)"

End Sub
```

I changed the above to

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

Dim cptrng As Range
Dim sumrng As Range
Dim cpt As String

Set cptrng = Sheets("CPTView").Range("A1:A1000")
Set sumrng = Sheets("CPTView").Range("C1:C1000")
cpt = ws.Range("C4").Value

ws.Range("C7").Formula = "=SumIf(" & cptrng & ", " & cpt & ", " & sumrng & ")"
```

The formula shows all of the correct cells and ranges but I now get a Type Mismatch error.
I think it's because the date formats aren't matching. The criteria date shows as "mm/dd/yyyy" but the range shows the dates as "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm".

Comment: cptrng and sumrng are ranges, they have now equivalant as a string when you use them in `"=SumIf(" & cptrng & ", " & cpt & ", " & sumrng & ")"` what is it you want that formula to be is it `=SumIf( a1:A1000, C4, C1:c1000` and if so what is it you're using VBA for?  what are you trying to achieve over just pasting this into the cell `C7`?  If thats not the formula you want could you elaborate on what it is you do want?

Comment: It looks as if your original question was answered and as you are now having a separate issue then you should post a new question related to that problem. Before you do so, carry out some research and if you get stuck, show the things that you have tried along with examples of cell values, results and expected results. Something to try is to separate the date from the date time value via formula then add that to your vba generated formula. Not sure how that would work on ranges but I think a single cell would be =int(a1) or whatever cell you want to reference.

Comment: Instead of building a string with `cptrng` you could use `cptrng.address` (answer updated accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Write a SUMIF Formula With VBA

```vb
Sub SumIfFormula()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "CPTView"
    Const slAddr As String = "A1:A1000" ' Lookup
    Const ssAddr As String = "C1:C1000" ' Sum
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Summary"
    Const dlAddr As String = "C4" ' Lookup
    Const dsAddr As String = "C7" ' Sum
    
    Dim Formula As String: Formula = "=SUMIF('" & sName & "'!" & slAddr & "," _
        & dlAddr & "," & "'" & sName & "'!" & ssAddr & ")"
    'Debug.Print Formula
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range(dsAddr).Formula = Formula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the formula string from a combination of text and variables.

Instead, you are literally inserting this formula:

```
=SumIf(cptrng, cpt, sumrng)
```

To get the effect you want, you have two options:

### Option 1

Build it on the fly, in this line:

```
ws.Range("C7").Formula = "=SumIf(cptrng, cpt, sumrng)"
```

By replacing it with:

```
ws.Range("C7").Formula = "=SumIf(" & cptrng.address & ", " & cpt & ", " & sumrng.address & ")"
```

### Option 2

Build a formula variable first, then set the formula as that variable.

Comment: agreed, in general but `cptrng` and `sumrng` are ranges not strings

Comment: updated accordingly